# Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility does not contain a definition for Redirect SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

i am trying to do a simple redirect from a visual web part, the user is going to enter a value on a textbox and redirect to a page.

i being trying to use SPUtility.Redirect but for some reason i can not,it says the method is not part of the definition as several others that i think should be there.

This is a SharePoint 2013 on visual studio 2013, the reference (Microsoft.SharePoint) is version 15 from this path:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Please let me know your comments. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://latenightsp.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/sharepoint-sandbox-limitations/

Basically it says

> Sandbox does not support re-direction – no Response.Redirect, no Server.Transfer,  no SPUtility.Redirect.`